# HTML file does not work on web brower, what should I do?

Tags: html, css

//My HTML webpage cannot be displayed on browsers. It is just plain text. Please review my codes and see what is wrong. T.T I tried many ways and still cannot find what is wrong. I would appreciate it if anyone can review it. Thank you! I also tried using internet explorer, chrome . Both of them don't work. Is it because of my formatting?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <style>
    header {
      text-align: center;
      background: url('https://i.imgur.com/2tQoKAI.jpeg');
      background-size: cover;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 6px 2px 3px black;

    }
    a {
      color: white;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 70px;
    }
    img {
      margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
      border: 7px solid white;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }
    ul {
      padding: 10px;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
    li {
      display: inline;
      padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    }
    article {
      max-width: 500px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    @media (max-width: 500px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 36px;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      li {
        padding: 5px;
        display: block;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GKTzyft.jpeg"
    width=200>
    <h1>Ben's Blog</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">How am I Handsome</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Meditation Music</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">My Beautiful Singing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
    <article>
      <h2>I am Born Handsome</h2>
      <p>As a natural handsome guy. I am born to be handsome. The handsomeness genes are within me. However, I am not only handsome, I am also talented in singing.</p>
      <button>Like</button>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>Meditate Daily</h2>
      <p>Meditation can help me become even more handsome and...wise. I mediate five minutes everyday to reflect on my life and explore my inner self. It is amazing to be enlightened.</p>
      <button>Like</button>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>I sing like Justin Timberlake/ Justin Bieber</h2>
      <p>Many people think all I've got is my handsome look. They are wrong! I also got a beautiful voice that soothes everyone's heart!</p>
      <button>Like</button>
    </article>
  <script>
    $("button").on("click", function() {
      alert("Clicked!");
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should probably be on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

After `<!DOCTYPE html>`, one should open with the `<html>` tag and on the end of the file, close with `</html>`.

This should result in something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
    <head> 
        ... 
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <style>
    header {
      text-align: center;
      background: url('https://i.imgur.com/2tQoKAI.jpeg');
      background-size: cover;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 6px 2px 3px black;

    }
    a {
      color: white;
    }
    h1 {
      font-size: 70px;
    }
    img {
      margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
      border: 7px solid white;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }
    ul {
      padding: 10px;
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
    li {
      display: inline;
      padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    }
    article {
      max-width: 500px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    @media (max-width: 500px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 36px;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      li {
        padding: 5px;
        display: block;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GKTzyft.jpeg"
    width=200>
    <h1>Ben's Blog</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">How am I Handsome</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Meditation Music</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">My Beautiful Singing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
    <article>
      <h2>I am Born Handsome</h2>
      <p>As a natural handsome guy. I am born to be handsome. The handsomeness genes are within me. However, I am not only handsome, I am also talented in singing.</p>
      <button>Like</button>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>Meditate Daily</h2>
      <p>Meditation can help me become even more handsome and...wise. I mediate five minutes everyday to reflect on my life and explore my inner self. It is amazing to be enlightened.</p>
      <button>Like</button>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h2>I sing like Justin Timberlake/ Justin Bieber</h2>
      <p>Many people think all I've got is my handsome look. They are wrong! I also got a beautiful voice that soothes everyone's heart!</p>
      <button>Like</button>
    </article>
  <script>
    $("button").on("click", function() {
      alert("Clicked!");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- Import Jquery
- Use `$(document).ready(function(){});`
- Open `<html>` tag and close `</html>` (it's optional but you can use its a best prectice and usefull for seo friendly website)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            header {
              text-align: center;
              background: url('https://i.imgur.com/2tQoKAI.jpeg');
              background-size: cover;
              color: white;
              font-weight: bold;
              text-shadow: 6px 2px 3px black;

            }
            a {
              color: white;
            }
            h1 {
              font-size: 70px;
            }
            img {
              margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
              border: 7px solid white;
              border-radius: 20px;
            }
            ul {
              padding: 10px;
              background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            }
            li {
              display: inline;
              padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
            }
            article {
              max-width: 500px;
              padding: 20px;
              margin: 0 auto;
            }
            @media (max-width: 500px) {
              h1 {
                font-size: 36px;
                padding: 5px;
              }
              li {
                padding: 5px;
                display: block;
              }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/GKTzyft.jpeg"
            width=200>
            <h1>Ben's Blog</h1>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">How am I Handsome</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Meditation Music</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">My Beautiful Singing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <article>
          <h2>I am Born Handsome</h2>
          <p>As a natural handsome guy. I am born to be handsome. The handsomeness genes are within me. However, I am not only handsome, I am also talented in singing.</p>
          <button>Like</button>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>Meditate Daily</h2>
          <p>Meditation can help me become even more handsome and...wise. I mediate five minutes everyday to reflect on my life and explore my inner self. It is amazing to be enlightened.</p>
          <button>Like</button>
        </article>
        <article>
          <h2>I sing like Justin Timberlake/ Justin Bieber</h2>
          <p>Many people think all I've got is my handsome look. They are wrong! I also got a beautiful voice that soothes everyone's heart!</p>
          <button>Like</button>
        </article>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>  
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("button").click(function(){
                    alert("Clicked!");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think is not a jquery problem

Comment: @Sfili_81 You can run the code snippet, i have added jquery

Answer (score -1):

Add this Jquery CDN

Refer : https://releases.jquery.com/

Thank you